# Error when trying add .xcassets in resources into podspec file

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I'm trying to create a CocoaPod but when I try to validate a pod spec file show me this error.

```
- ERROR | [iOS] unknown: Encountered an unknown error (Unable to find other source ref for /Users/jhgonzalez/Desktop/MyApp/Me/cocoaPod/JCore-ui/LibraryComponents/Resources/JCore-ui.xcassets/Contents.json for target JCore-ui.) during validation.
```

This is my podspec file.

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
s.name             = 'JCore'
s.version          = '0.2.3'
s.summary          = 'This is an UI Lib for iOS'
s.platform         = :ios, "10.0"

s.description      = <<-DESC
                  This is an UI Lib to iOS. This description is too large than summary 
                   DESC

s.license          = { :type => 'MIT', :file => 'LICENSE' }
s.author           = { 'Josue Hernandez' => 'example@gmail.com' }
s.source           = { :git => 'https://github.com/example/JCore.git', :tag => s.version.to_s }

s.source_files = 'LibraryComponents/**/*'

s.resource_bundles = {
'JCore' => ['LibraryComponents/Resources/*.xcassets','LibraryComponents/Resources/**/*.json']
}
```

Any idea.

Comment: Hii you got the solution ? i am facing same issue

Comment: Hi, just wondering if you found any solution

Answer (score 0):

```
s.source_files = 'LibraryComponents/**/*' ->  
s.source_files = 'LibraryComponents/**/*.{swift}'
```

it looks like "*" covered all files.

hope can help you.

Comment: Answer should have more details. Try to elaborate a little more